# How can I move terminal cursor by word?

Tags: terminal, move, cursor

CentOS zsh terminal, the path just typed or copied is very deep, need to change a word in the middle.
`Ctrl-f` or `Ctrl-b` can move cursor by one character.
Is there a way to move cursor by word, like vim?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/acamino/2bc8df5e2ed0f99ddbe7a6fddb7773a6

Comment: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/keyboard-shortcuts-in-bash-and-zsh/

Comment: do you have zsh set to use emacs, or vi mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `CRTL+Arrow Left` or `CRTL+Arrow Right`